# Angularjs common controller

Tags: angularjs

In my rails app,I have a layout `top.slim`

```
div[ng-app="topApp"]
  div[ng-controller="InboxCtrl"]
    ul
     li[ng-repeat="item in items"]
       ....
  ....
```

the js is

```
var topApp = angular.module('topApp',[])
memApp.controller('InboxCtrl',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.items = [{},{}]
})
```

And every page has it's own `ng-app`   like

```
htm[ng-app="..."]
  ....
  =render "top"
```

Now the angularjs did't work,It seems that the `ng-app` can't be nested.

But I just want to add a controller in the common page to bind data.what should I do?

Comment: from the given code line `Now the angularjs did't work,It seems that the ng-app can't be nested.` doesnt match.. how u r having nested `app`? and what exactly u want.. for one page application we generally have one `ng-app` and multiple `controller`

Comment: The pattern is to have one module in the html (one ng-app) and multiple, eventually nested ng-controller or controller. I guessing you may want to look into routing https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: If you're absolutely sure that you need multiple `ng-app` directives on one page, then you'll need to [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization) your app manually.

Comment: I just want to add the `InboxCtrl` to every page's module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick to a single "app". Remove ng-app from top.slim div, and declare your controllers on the same module (could be sub-modules if you want).

layout top.slim

```
div
  div[ng-controller="InboxCtrl"]
    ul
     li[ng-repeat="item in items"]
       ....
  ....
```

the js is

```
var topApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
memApp.controller('InboxCtrl',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.items = [{},{}]
})
```

And every page has it's own ng-app like

```
html[ng-app="myApp"]
  ....
  =render "top"
```

Comment: So,I want to know if I write `html[ng-app]` in html,what the js would like? `var topApp = angular.module('',[])`, can I do this?